# JTree dont update when I`m trying to add it to JFrame

Tags: java, swing

When I am trying to dynamically update my JTree it works nice, but displays only my new tree. But then I am trying to add it to a JFrame - nothing happens. JTree doesnt update. And I can`t understand why.

```
public MainForm(){

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("ROOT");                 
    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

    tree = new JTree(model);

    buildTree(model, "Node 1/Node 2/Node 3/Node 4");
    buildTree(model, "Node 1/Node 2/Node 3/Node 5");
    buildTree(model, "Node 1/Node 2/Node 3/Node 6");
    buildTree(model, "Node 1/Node 2/Node 4/Node 5");
    buildTree(model, "Node 1/Node 1/Node 3/Node 5");


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(tree);
    frame.setSize(900, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //if I comment next line I`ll get just a tree in my frame (but updated 
    //as I wanted);
    //But if not I`ve got my form with buttons and tree, but tree doesn`t 
    //update
    frame.setContentPane(rootMainForm);

}
```

Comment: You are aware that this piece of code tells nothing? unknown `buildTree` unknown `rootMainForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `tree` to the `rootMainForm` as well.

This line

```
frame.add(tree)
```

adds tree to the `ContentPane`
 while this line

```
frame.setContentPane(rootMainForm);
```

overrides whole `ContentPane` of the frame. My bet is that you have 2 JTrees. When you  comment last line, you will see most recent added component (`tree` here).  When you uncomment it, you are overriding the whole content of frame with unknnown panel `rootMainForm`

Your comment makes me think, that you try to update your jtree in this line actually

```
 tree = new JTree(model);
```

Well this will create brand new `JTree` that is detached from GUI. If you want to update your existing JTree, just use `tree.setModel(model)` insteed of `tree=new JTree(model)`

Comment: But according to MainForm.form I`ve got 1 JTree and it is in my rootMainForm.

[link](https://pp.userapi.com/c841335/v841335869/25d24/-iXWulTfT24.jpg)

Comment: But you are creating new JTree here `tree = new JTree(model);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience! I was a bit tired or dumb I suppose ><

Comment: @AleksanderIksanov No worries. Such mistakes happens when you are learning something new:) good luck!